# How to change field values in a view programatically?

Tags: views, theming, 6

I'm working in a custom module that displays date fields. I want to be able to change the date's timezone programmatically.

I've tried implementing `hook_views_pre_render()`, but that doesn't allow me to format the field value. I'd really like to do the theming inside my module code since that's where the logic is regarding my timezone.

As a total hack, I could use `hook_views_post_render()`, but then I'd be doing search/replace on the text and that seems like a poor solution.

What other hooks inside my module are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after a little more googling I found my own answer on a [thread on d.o](https://drupal.org/node/1407442) that address this issue with sample code (which I'm condensing a bit):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements HOOK_preprocess_views_view_fields().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];

  //Replace 'VIEW_NAME' with the machine_name of your view.
  if($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {

    //This for loop iterates over all fields in this view.
    foreach ($vars['fields'] as $id => $field) {

      //Custom formatting logic goes here....

      //Set the field value (not the surrounding tags) here.
      $vars['fields'][$id]->content = 'my new value';        
    }
  }
}
?>
```

**NOTE** Make sure you replace "MYTHEME" with the name of your theme or module in order for this work.